# Ordenar array por un rango de fechas en Javascript

Tags: javascript, sortable

Tengo un array de objetos en Javascript con dos campos:

```
data = [
0: {'max_date': '22-10-2022', 'min_date':'21-10-2022'},
1: {'max_date': '21-10-2022', 'min_date':'23-10-2022'},
2: {'max_date': '25-10-2022', 'min_date':'22-10-2022'},
3: {'max_date': '19-10-2022', 'min_date':'22-10-2022'},
]
```

Estoy intentando ordenar por el más rápido, o sea por max_date

```
  data = data.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.max_date) > new Date(b.max_date) ? 1 : -1,reverse=true)
```

Pero no consigo que funcione. De todas maneras, lo ideal sería ordenar por la suma de dias en restar max_date - min_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en cómo estás creando los objetos Date.

Si pruebas a parsear directamente tus strings te encuentras con lo siguiente:

```js
//Formato nativo de fecha:
test_1 = new Date('10/22/2022');

// Tu formato
test_2 = new Date('22-10-2022');

console.log(test_1);
// "2022-10-21T22:00:00.000Z"

console.log(test_2);
// null
```

Puedes crear una función que convierta a `Date`desde `dd-mm-yyyy`y utilizarla en el `.sort()`:

```js
data = [
 {'max_date': '22-10-2022', 'min_date':'21-10-2022'},
 {'max_date': '21-10-2022', 'min_date':'23-10-2022'},
 {'max_date': '25-10-2022', 'min_date':'22-10-2022'},
 {'max_date': '19-10-2022', 'min_date':'22-10-2022'},
]

const fecha = (s) => {
  const [dia, mes, ano] = s.split("-")
  return new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia)
}

data_ordenado = data.sort((a,b) => fecha(a.max_date) > fecha(b.max_date) ? 1 : -1,reverse=true);
```

---

Pero si lo que quieres es ordenar por la diferencia de días podrías hacerlo directamente con los strings ya convertidos a fecha:

```javascript
data_ordenado = data.sort((a,b) => fecha(a.max_date) - fecha(a.min_date) > fecha(b.max_date) - fecha(b.min_date) ? 1 : -1,reverse=true);
```

El problema es que en tu array de entrada tienes cosas mal definidas, ya que min_date en ocasiones es mayor que max_date.

Comment: Gracias, es lo que buscaba.